# How can I sort a key within the dictionaries into descending order?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am very new to python and I would like to sort all the maximum scores into descending order. (There is a dictionary that stores the data for each student) At the moment it only prints the maximum scores of each student in the order the data is entered:

```
Maximum score
Adam Watts 7
Henry Lloyd 10
Lucy Smith 9
```

This is the code I am using:

```
print("Maximum score")
for key in keys:
    print(key, max(Classes[key]))
```

Comment: How does your dictionary look like, exactly? What result do you expect? Just printing? Please edit your post such that it makes sense.

Comment: What is the structure of you dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dictionary is like this:

```
students = {'Adam Watts': [3, 7], 'Henry Lloyd': [10, 1], 'Lucy Smith': [9, 9]}
```

You cannot sort a dictionary (entries in a dictionary have no particular order), but your can store the data that you care about in a list, and sort this list.

```
from operator import itemgetter
items = [(student, max(scores)) for student, scores in students.items()]
items.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

for student, score in items:
    print(student, score)
```